# How to change the sheet that linked objects in google slides point to?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-slides-api, google-slides

In google slides you can have linked objects which is a chart or a range in sheet that you can view in slides. If you change the chart or the range in sheets then you can click update in slides and you will be able to see the changes.

The problem is that I can't find a way to change which sheet the linked object points to.
So if I have a table in slides that is linked to a range in one sheet, how do I change it to link to another sheet?

The reason I want to be able to change the linked object form one sheet to another is so it is possible to make a template for google slides and a template for a google sheet. Then when you want to make a new instance of the templates then you are able to change the linked objects in the new google slides instance to point to the new instance of the google sheet document.

I work in a company where we make a lot of google slides reports based on google sheet data.

I have tried looking through the different interface in google slides and it seems like this is not possible.

Now if there is a way to be able to fix this using google scripts then that would also work. I know how to code in javascript and have worked have made some scripts in google scripts before. If it is possible to do without coding then that would be amazing since it would be much easier to set it up for people in our business.

Answer (score 3):

We're looking for this too and sad to find it still does not exist.

We have created a great Google Slides template, however if we duplicate it for others to use it is virtually useless....because all the charts need to be replaced as we cannot re-link them to a new Google Sheet.

Also it is not possible to 'unlink' and then manually link the unlinked chart - the charts all must be completely deleted from the Google Slide then re-added from a new sheet + all the repositioning, resizing etc :(

Answer (score 0):

We have no possibility to "re-link" embedded SheetsChart objects (by script or manually).
Another way is to make all the necessary chart modifications inside the spreadsheet and [refresh](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/sheets-chart#refresh) embedded object afterwards. In particular, it is useful for small [data range changes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-chart-builder#addrangerange).